# Stream data in Flask using sub process

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, subprocess

So, basically I am making a web streaming service and I streamed the webcam video in browser using opencv with flask:

```
def gen(camera):
    frame  = camera.get_frame()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame.tobytes() + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

And this is working fine. Now I have a stream of data being generated when the user looks into the webcam( lets say face points). I want to stream this data to the browser using a subprocess. This is what I have written so far:

**Server side**

```
@app.route('/yield')
def conso():
    def inner():
        proc = subprocess.Popen(                 # where L is the stream of data
        L,            
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
        time.sleep(1)                         
        yield ( line.rstrip() + b'\r\n')

return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

**Client Side**

```
<script>
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/yield');
  source.onmessage = function(e) {
  $("#data").text(e.data);
  }
 }
</script>
<div id="data">nothing received yet</div>
```

But is does't able to stream any data. Neither it is giving any errors. Can someone help me to identify where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had dealt with a problem like this and it was that the *$(#data)* selector was not working, could you try using *document.getElementById* to test if that fixes the problem:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var source = new EventSource('/yield');
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + '<br>';
        };
    </script>
```